# onmouseout Event after clicking on link

Tags: javascript

[image: Actual Page]

Here after clicking on the link onmouseout event should be called.I'm very poor in Javascript & need help in this

Required something like this
[image]

when I enter into the block of reporting,& click on subscribe then mouseout event occurs.The same functionality I want here
My code

```
<style>
    .helpLink {
      position:relative;
    }

    .videoPanel {
      display:none;
      width:160px;
      height:120px;
      background:#EEE;
      border:1px solid #CCC;

      position:absolute;
      left:-160px;
      z-index:10;
    }
  </style>

       <apex:outputLink styleClass="helpLink" onmouseover="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display = 'block';" title="help" onmouseout="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display = 'none';" >
                <apex:image value="/s.gif" styleClass="helpIcon" />
            </apex:outputLink>
            <apex:outputPanel id="Foo" styleClass="video" title="help" >
               <a  href="google.com" target="_blank" onmouseout="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display = 'none';">link</a>
               <a href="youtube.com" target="_blank" onmouseout="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display = 'none';">Video</a>
            </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Need not go for javascript .Onmouseout events are supported on many VF tags .Just you may need action function

Comment: What exactly are you experiencing? What is the expected behavior? Can you please include the code you have already written in your question for us to take a look at it? We need some more information here.

Comment: My requirement is like this say suppose when u mouseover on tags here on 'javascript'  u'll be getting '7 followers, Rss,subscribe & so on'.Now here I can click on the link rss & when i mouseout this will disappear.The same functionality requries for me.Modified my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 reasons that your current `onMouseOut` and `onMouseOver` code is not working:

1. Your jQuery id selector needs to be preceded with the '#' sign --- the Visualforce `$Component.<componentName>` syntax only gives you the Component's Id, but does not prefix it with a `#' sign, which is the selector for getting a DOM element by its Id.
2. The best way to show/hide an element with jQuery is to use the `$(selector).show()`, `.hide()`, or `.toggle()` methods. If you explicitly want to set the `display` property, then use `$(selector).css('display','block')`
3. For complex Visualforce element trees, as mast0r suggested, the best way to get at an element is to use the "attribute ends with" selector, as Visualforce automatically generates unique DOM Ids that generally are not equal to the "id" attribute that you assign in your Visualforce Page definition. For instance, if you had `<apex:outputLink id="Foo" value="http://apple.com">`, the generated DOM might be something like `<a href="http://apple.com" id="j_id0:Foo"/>`. So the best practice for accessing DOM elements by Id with jQuery in Visualforce is to do this: `jQuery('[id$=<visualforceId>]').hide()`, or in your case, `jQuery('[id$=Foo]').hide()`;

So, with these in mind, here is how you can adjust your 2 handlers:

```
<apex:outputLink styleClass="helpLink" title="help"
    onmouseover="jQuery('[id$=Foo]').css('display','block');"
    onmouseover="jQuery('[id$=Foo]').css('display','none');">
```

Comment: the `$` is the browser's native document.querySelector function, not jQuery

Comment: further, I would respectfully suggest that we encourage OP to use the sanctioned `{!$Component}` notation and learn about component hierarchy, instead of doing a partial string match using a third-party library... http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm

Comment: @user31, with respect, the "sanctioned" method is (1) a true pain to get correct in complex pages, even if you are an experienced developer who understands the component hierarchy (2) not always applicable, as sometimes you are looking to alter a rendered DOM element that Visualforce does not identify according to the hierarchy. As to the point about $ being the native `document.querySelector`, IE 6 and 7 do not support it, and as Salesforce supports IE 6 & 7, SFDC devs might consider it), so it is much safer to use jQuery, plus jQuery provides additional helpful selectors (`:has`,`:contains`)

Comment: pardon @zachelrath, fair call - didn't mean to contest the merits of selector libraries; just noting for consistency that OP's question is a copypasta from a previous answer, and the `$` identifier does not refer to the `jQuery` object per your answer; the lib is absent entirely on his page

Comment: @zachelrath here when I mouseout from the block (i.e., jQuery('[id$=Foo]').css('display','block');) which is displayed by mouseover on the image ?,then mouseout event should work.Simultaneously when I enter into the block mouseout event shouldn't work.Any Idea on how to do this?

Comment: @EagerinSf I'm not exactly sure in which order you're trying to show/hide various elements, so I'd experiment with [mast0r's jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afwfT/9/) to try to achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE

Ok, then just creating an extra javascript function for the onmouseout action and will call this functiona after onmouseclick:

```
<apex:outputLink styleClass="helpLink" 
                 onmouseover="jQuery('[id$=Foo]').show()"
                 onclick="doOnclick();">
...
</apex:outputLink>

<script>
function doOnclick() {
    // Do your onclick actions here
    ...
    // After that calling mouse-out function
    doMouseOut();
}

function doMouseOut() {
    // Do your stuff for mouse out action
    jQuery('[id$=Foo]').hide();
}
</script>
```

---

I think you need just some css and jquery code.

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/afwfT/9/

[image]

Comment: Here Param1 is of Hyperlink type & I need to click on it

Comment: Ok, then replace in code `Param 1` to `<a href="google.com">Param 1</a>`

Comment: here my problem is I can't able to click on Param 1 because their is a mouseout action on it `<apex:outputLink styleClass="helpLink" onmouseover="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display = 'none';" >` after clicking on hyperlink mouseout event should occur.How can I do it

Comment: @EagerinSf I think i got it now. Updated my example.

Comment: @eyescream http://i.imgur.com/TJdhVS2.gif

Comment: @mast0r  here when I mouseout from the block (i.e., jQuery('[id$=Foo]').css('display','block');) which is displayed by mouseover on the image ?,then mouseout event should work.Simultaneously when I enter into the block mouseout event shouldn't work.Any Idea on how to do this?